# How to convert character to time and add it to date?

Tags: r, datetime

I have offset time between UTC and local time at different locations as following (+/-HH:MM):

```
> x
# [1] "+00:00" "+00:00" "-03:00" "+01:00" "+03:00" "+03:00" "+00:00" "+01:00"
# [9] "+00:00" "+00:00" "+02:00" "+01:00" "+02:00" "-02:00" "+00:00" "+01:00"
```

How can I convert this to a time interval, then use it to shift `Sys.Date()` using the numbers above?

Comment: use `hours` of `lubridate` package `Sys.Date() + hours(2)` and so on.

Comment: how to make the above number understandable for lubridate as time interval?

Comment: They are character strings am I right?

Comment: if you google the title of this question, the first four or five results are possible solutions

Comment: Yes. > class(x)
[1] "character"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `as.difftime` (there is a bit of gymnastics to do because it doesn't recognized signed character input):

```
x <- c("+00:00","+00:00","-03:00","+01:00","+03:00","+03:00","+00:00","+01:00","+00:00","+00:00","+02:00","+01:00","+02:00","-02:00","+00:00","+01:00")
as.difftime(gsub("[+-]","",x), format ="%H:%M") * ifelse(grepl("^-",x),-1,1)
#Time differences in secs
# [1]      0      0 -10800   3600  10800  10800      0   3600      0      0   7200   3600   7200  -7200      0   3600
#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] ""
```

So to shift from `Sys.time()`, it's simply:

```
Sys.time()+as.difftime(gsub("[+-]","",x),format ="%H:%M") * ifelse(grepl("^-",x),-1,1)
 #[1] "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 07:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 11:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 13:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 13:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST"
 #[8] "2015-07-10 11:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 12:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 11:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 12:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 08:36:32 CEST"
 #[15] "2015-07-10 10:36:32 CEST" "2015-07-10 11:36:32 CEST"
```

If you had your input as numbers, it would be even more straightforward, since it does recognized signed numeric input:

```
y <- c(-1,2,3,0,-4,-6.5)
Sys.time() + as.difftime(y, units="hours")
# [1] "2015-07-10 09:39:31 CEST" "2015-07-10 12:39:31 CEST" "2015-07-10 13:39:31 CEST" "2015-07-10 10:39:31 CEST" "2015-07-10 06:39:31 CEST" "2015-07-10 04:09:31 CEST"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it finally this way, but your solution is much neater than mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here I have a (clumsy) solution, but it works I think. Waiting for more elegant solutions. Steps are, `gsub` to strings all punctuations and the `+` sign. convert them all in numeric, divide by 100 in order to have, example -200 as -2, and them pass them all as arguments of the `hours` function.

```
library(lubridate)
x1 <- gsub("[:punct:]|\\+", "", x)
x1 <- as.numeric(as.character(x1))
x1 <- x1 / 100

Sys.Date() + hours(x1)
[1] "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC"
[3] "2015-07-08 21:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 01:00:00 UTC"
[5] "2015-07-09 03:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 03:00:00 UTC"
[7] "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 01:00:00 UTC"
[9] "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC"
[11] "2015-07-09 02:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 01:00:00 UTC"
[13] "2015-07-09 02:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-08 22:00:00 UTC"
[15] "2015-07-09 00:00:00 UTC" "2015-07-09 01:00:00 UTC"
```

data I have used:

```
x <- c("+00:00", "+00:00", "-03:00", "+01:00", "+03:00", "+03:00", "+00:00", "+01:00",
"+00:00", "+00:00", "+02:00", "+01:00", "+02:00", "-02:00", "+00:00", "+01:00")
```

#### Edit: a solution for minutes too

Here the data used is the vector `y` that contains minutes too.

```
y <- c("+03:30", "+02:45", "-03:50", "-05:00")
y1 <- unlist(strsplit(y, "[:punct:]"))
y1 <- gsub("\\+", "", y1)
y1 <- as.numeric(as.character(y1))
MinuteS <- y1[1:length(y1) %% 2 == 0]
HourS <- y1[1:length(y1) %% 2 == 1]

 Sys.Date() + minutes(MinuteS) + hours(HourS)
[1] "2015-07-09 03:30:00 UTC"
[2] "2015-07-09 02:45:00 UTC"
[3] "2015-07-08 21:50:00 UTC"
[4] "2015-07-08 19:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: only problem with this solution is that sometime I have minutes also such as  09:30 ;(

Comment: I based my solutions to the sample **you** have provided. If you have other data at least you should specify them in you question. Anyway, that said (hoping it is useful for next questions you'll ask here) it can be fixed easy I think.

Comment: @newbie I have added a new solution.

Comment: @newbie I do not understand what you are saying. Maybe it is better to open another question for this (other) specific issue.